# Does inheritance of DateTime change any default function behavior?

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to know, if a inherited class from DateTime still has its super class default behavior function for comparing dates when I am use it on 2 instances of my own specialised class, which implements the magical __toString() method?

What I exactly mean is easier to explain in code:

```
class OwnDate extends DateTime
{
public function __toString()
{
return $this->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
}
$date1 = new OwnDate('2013-12-31');
$date2 = new OwnDate('2014-01-01');

if ($date1 < $date2)
{
// does this comparsion above work?
}
```

I mean, I am not sure, what PHP internal calls, to get the date comparsion from two DateTime object working. Normally in C# if you do something like this:

```
int i = 10;
Console.WriteLine("i is " + i);
```

C# will parse it to this code:

```
int i = 10;
Console.WriteLine("i is " + i.ToString());
```

If PHP does it the same way, my comparsion above should not work, right? I tried to find the source code from the PHP class DateTime, but I could not find it. Any help in this special question would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I didn´t. I guess a strange exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement/extend a class, the parent class (in this case `DateTime`) will pass its methods to the child class(`OwnDate`), unless you override them. Ergo, the methods in `DateTime` should still function the same way as they did if you used the`DateTime` class directly.

Comment: You´re right. I got the courage to test it on phpfiddle: http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/6af-acg and yes, it works as expected. Date comparsion still works.

Comment: @alpham8 You're not going to break anything by experimenting and trying things like this for yourself. Reading the manual and trying things for yourself is the way to learn.

Comment: I know object orientated programming and all the four basic principes. But this was a PHP special behavior, which handles every oo programming language in an other way. E. g. in C# DateTime is only a struct, so an own defined datatype, which you can compare with ease. But structs are unknown in PHP, so it must be a whole class. And I wasn´t sure before, how PHP internal handle comparsion on objects (what value will be returned? The reference or any data?). So thanks to all for your technical support.